# DB design Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am designing db structure for a service provider. Here is what I have so far:

```
+---------+  +----------+  +-----------------+  +-----------------+
| User    |  | Order    |  | OrderItems      |  | Subscription    |
+---------+  +----------+  +-----------------+  +-----------------+
| user_id +--+ order_id +--+ order_id        +--+ subscription_id |
+---------+  | user_id  |  | subscription_id |  | user_id         |
             +----------+  +-----------------+  | service_plan_id |
                                                +--------+--------+
                                                         |
 +------------------+   +-------------------+   +--------+--------+
 | ServiceGroup     |   | ServicePlanAccess |   | ServicePlan     |
 +------------------+   +-------------------+   +-----------------+
 | service_group_id +---+ service_plan_id   +---+ service_plan_id |
 +------------------+   | service_group_id  |   +-----------------+
                        +-------------------+
```

1. Should I remove *user_id* from table *Subscription*? It seems redundant but it may be easier to get a user's active subscriptions without multiple table joins.

There is a differentiation between a service group and a service plan - a service group defines direct access to Service A or B. A service plan may include more than one service group, therefore granting access to multiple Services (e.g. access A+B). Here is an example where plan 3 gives access to groups 1 and 2:

```
+--------------------+
| ServicePlanAccess  |
+--------------------+
| plan_id | group_id |
+--------------------+
| 1       | 1        |
| 2       | 2        |
| 3       | 1        |
| 3       | 2        |
+--------------------+
```

2. Is this a sensible db design and can it be improved?

Comment: 1) Keep user_id in the Subscription table.  2) Right now, your tables are defined such that each subscription has a service plan, which can have one or more service groups.  If you want a subscription to have direct access to service groups, without a service plan, you'll need one more junction table that ties subscriptions to service groups.

Comment: Redundancy is _usually_ bad in a schema design.  It is bad because it is too easy to get the two copies of user_id out of sync.